# sbt build issue - IO error while decoding code.scala with UTF-8

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to sbt assembly my code (script.scala) on my Windows 7 machine using cmd, and I am getting the above posted error.

I have also tried to set this on cmd
`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF8'` but it still does not help.

I am editing the file using Notepad++ and once the jar is built running it on my Hadoop cluster.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930230/scala-error-io-error-while-decoding-with-utf-8 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala "error: io error while decoding" "with utf-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930230/scala-error-io-error-while-decoding-with-utf-8)